# detecting the router's ip address using arp command

Tags: router, ip, arp

When I use the command `arp -a` I get the list of IPs in my network. the first IP address after the address of my own pc (that I run command) is the IP address of the router.

I want to know is the router's IP address always the first one? (and can I always count on it to be the router's IP address?) or can it just appear anywhere in the list?

Comment: no. the order of the entries in the arp table, when output, is not meaningful to define the type or class of device. I'd guess that the second entry in your ARP table will be the first host you contacted, since your last reboot, but thats just a guess.

Comment: then, is there a command to get the router's ip address?

Comment: @Failure A command for what? We have no idea what software you're using. Also, can you define precisely what you mean by "router". Do you mean default gateway?

Comment: you can determine the default gateway router's IP address in windows with `ipconfig /all` and look at 'default gateway', or in linux with `netstat -r`.

Comment: @FrankThomas That command doesn't work for me. I get `bash: ipconfig: command not found`. But `arp -a` works fine.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes I was looking for the ipconfig /all command, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this question was fully answered ... the answers are in line with: "how to display the gateway address stored in the local device network configuration file" ... what I think was being asked is whether there was some way to determine what the default gateway address is by using a tool like arp

With the proliferation of cheap IoT devices, my personal concern is whether these devices might be able to find the default gateway to allow them to "PHONE HOME" ... I configure ALL my IoT devices with nonstandard Port(s) and Static IP Addresses plus also point Gateway, and DNS Addresses to this same Static Address ... I also don't use generic Addresses for Gateways

Example:
Router Default Gateway: 192.168.0.42 Netmask: 255.255.254.0
IoT device fixed IP: 192.168.1.220 Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway = DNS1 = DNS2 = 192.168.1.220
Port 80 -> 6218

In this configuration, can something like arp be used by the IoT to find the actual Gateway Address?

Most IoTs don't come with a huge amount of memory so doubt they would squirrel away a WireShark or other sniffer software ... so far, touch wood, this simple technique appears to have kept my networks safe

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151544)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).